# Como comparar un campo string con uno de fecha MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongod

tengo una coleccion de datos en mongodb, donde mi documento almacena una fecha en tipo string, pero me en mi endpoint me envia un rango de fecha para validar la busqueda.
como podria convertir directamente en la query de mongodb el campo string en fecha para poder filtrar,
he intentado convertir la fecha a un string y comparar con $regex pero no logro hacer que funcione en rango.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5se5r489ad1f78ga879854dadf8787a1sdkkhuir879"
},
"codigocliente": "168a51g",
"proceso": "654655",
"producto": "Carro",
"nombresegmento": "Respuesta",
"cer_nombre": "CARLOSSANCHEZ",
"cer_ncuenta": "2256558468",
"cer_nrut": "9999999-9",
"fecha": "08/10/2020"}}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo del *rango* al que te refieres? Además sería bueno que mostraras lo que has intentado y un ejemplo de la salida esperada. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: el rango es de un año me pasan un string "/2020" y debo buscarlo en la base de datos que se encuentra en formato string "10/11/2020" con un $regex:{"/2020"}, me trae toda la informacion del 2020, pero debo crear otra funcion que me calcula como pasar la busqueda por un año, al usar $regex no puedo crear un rango como 
{$regex:"/2020",$regex"/2019"} ya que solo me toma la ultima consulta,

Comment: asi que creo que lo mejor es en la busqueda en mongo, convertir el campo string de fecha a un datatime y conparar con la fecha ya calculada en data time

Answer (score 1):

Para no cambiar tu base de datos a que sea un formato Date, se puede hacer lo siguiente:

- Para un rango de fecha completo (año, mes, dia, horas,...):

  ```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              dateInit, // Variable de tipo Date con la fecha inicial
              {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$fecha",
                  format: "%d/%m/%Y" // Formato de la fecha a parsear
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              dateEnd,  // Variable de tipo Date con la fecha final
              {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$fecha",
                  format: "%d/%m/%Y"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ])
  ```
- Para un rango de años:

  ```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                $year: dateInit // Variable de tipo Date con la fecha inicial
              },
              {
                $year: {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$fecha",
                    format: "%d/%m/%Y"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              {
                $year: dateEnd // Variable de tipo Date con la fecha final
              },
              {
                $year: {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$fecha",
                    format: "%d/%m/%Y"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ])
  ```

Más info sobre [dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/).

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar, sino no dudes en preguntar.

Un saludo